# Bootstrap: close modal and save changes

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
```

Is it possible close modal window and save changes with a single button. I have not found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `data-dismiss="modal"`attribute to your Save Changes button. Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8698/